# How do I convert a JavaScript object to a MongoDB BSON object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have the following Javascript object, how can I convert it to BSON for insert in MongoDB (and transform those date string in ISODate)?

```
{ name: 'Event 4',
  personsMax: 2,
  begin: '2014-09-22T19:00:20.000Z',
  end: '2014-09-22T21:00:20.000Z',
  creator: 'Jack',
  created: '2014-09-22T14:52:20.517Z',
  refDate: '2014-10-08T00:00:00.000Z',
  whoIsIn: { jack: true },
 id: 4 }
```

I'm using nod.js + node-mongodb-native client.

After db.insert in mongodb I have:

db.test.find();

```
{ "name" : "Event 4", "personsMax" : 2, "begin" : "2014-09-22T19:00:20.000Z", 
"end" : "2014-09-22T21:00:20.000Z", "creator" : "Jack", 
"created" : "2014-09-22T14:52:20.517Z", "refDate" : "2014-10-08T00:00:00.000Z", 
"whoIsIn" : { "jack" : true }, "id" : 4, "_id" : ObjectId("542038e4a3fbfcf81bace0d7") }
```

I suspect those "begin", "end", "created", "refDate" fields was inserted as String, not Date (or ISODate).

I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want convert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything to BSON. Mongo handles this for you. Mongo only uses BSON to store it's data internally - you interface with it using JSON and your library code (in your case `node-mongodb-native`).

With regard to the date objects - you can create them as normal [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects - again, mongo will handle these and convert them as needed during the insertion process.

Comment: Better explained, sorry

Comment: Insert your dates as proper JavaScript date objects and they will be converted to ISODate

Comment: You're right, I "typeof'ed" obj.refDate and it's a string. ^_^"